# Inserting data into a file

Tags: java, performance, strings, file

So, given a file with the following format:

> [header]
>   line of data
>   line of data
>   line of data
>   line of data
>
> [header 2]
>   line of data
>   line of data
>   line of data
>
> ...

I add a line of data to a specific header so the result would be:

> ...
>   [target header]
>   line of data
>   ...
>   new line inserted

The program currently only adds lines but is written so it accepts an input file that lists instructions with the format `instruction|[header]|line to add` e.g.  A|[Passions]|Code Review would add Code Review to the Passions section.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdjustList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("No arguments provided.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] commandParameters = fileScanner.nextLine().split("\\|");
                if (commandParameters.length != 3) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameter format");
                }

                File targetFile = new File("ImportantList.md");
                processCommand(targetFile, commandParameters[0], commandParameters[1], commandParameters[2]);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.err.println("File doesn't exist / wrong directory");
        }
    }

    private static void processCommand(File file, String instruction, String targetSection, String inputLine) {
        boolean taskComplete = false;
        StringBuilder fileBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            if (instruction.equals("A")) { // add
                System.out.println("Adding " + inputLine + " to " + targetSection);
                while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                    if (line.equals(targetSection)) {
                        fileBuilder.append(line).append('\n');
                        while (!taskComplete) {
                            line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                                fileBuilder.append(inputLine).append('\n');
                                taskComplete = true;
                            } else {
                                fileBuilder.append(line).append('\n');
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        fileBuilder.append(line).append('\n');
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.err.println("File doesn't exist / wrong directory");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        writeOutput(file, fileBuilder.toString());
    }

    private static void writeOutput(File file, String output) {
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8")) {
            writer.write(output);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

The file is read, line by line, storing the input into a `StringBuilder` with the additional line added based on a flag. This works but I get the feeling it's not the cleanest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Input validation

It looks like if `instruction` is not `"A"`, then you will be overwriting `"ImportantList.md"` with the contents of ***an empty*** `StringBuilder`.

#### `Iterable`-based processing

If the file sizes you are dealing with are relatively small enough to fit contents in memory, you can consider reading them in as a `List`, do the required processing, then write it out via [`Files.write(Path, Iterable, Charset, OpenOption)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-). This avoids having to concatenate `\n` repetitively while using the `StringBuilder`. For example:

```
private static void process(Path path, String targetHeader, String newLine) {
    List<String> lines = null;
    try {
        lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle error here
    }
    int index = lines.indexOf(targetHeader);
    if (index == -1) {
        // log that target header is not found?
        return;
    }
    int i = index + 1;
    for (; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        if (lines.get(i).isEmpty()) {
            lines.add(i, newLine);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i == lines.size()) {
        lines.add(newLine);
    }
    try {
        Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle error here
    }   
}
```

Here, we also handle the case where the target header is the last header and there is no trailing newline at the end of the text file, using the comparison `i == lines.size()`.

Answer (score 2):

### Misleading Message?

> ```
>     if (args.length != 1) {
>         System.err.println("No arguments provided.");
>         System.exit(1);
>     }
> ```

So if I have 2 arguments, I get the message `No arguments provided`. Umm... I provided 2 arguments!

#### Suggested fix:

Change the above code to:

```
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.err.println("No arguments provided.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

And you can possible warn the user about only requiring one argument if they provide too much. Something like:

```
    if (args.length > 1) {
        System.out.println("Warning! Too many arguments; only the first one will be considered.");
    }
```